# Многостраничный сайт. Подключение шапки и подвала

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Как организовать подключение шапки и подвала на страницы в сайте, чтобы постоянно не писать их? Без использования php

Comment: обычно используется общий шаблон и в него включается контент страницы. слишком общий вопрос не видя Вашего кода или текущего алгоритма подключения шапки и подвала.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что я не знаю, как подключить шапку на все страницы сайта.

Comment: Если без использования php, то с использованием чего? Вы пишете обыкновенный html без привлечения дополнительных инструментов? Если так, то как насчёт использовать какой-нибудь генератор статических сайтов?

Comment: Я слышал про SSI, Gulp и т.п.

Comment: @ДмитрийМаслов приведите код Вашей страницы - как сейчас Вы подключаете шапку ?

Comment: Я просто обычно копирую всегда шапку(весь код) и вставляю его в другие страницы. Сейчас хочу узнать, как можно не делать этого постоянно

Comment: В конце-концов при посадке вёрстки на cms в большинстве случаев происходит разбивка на php - шаблоны. Для работы на локальном компьютере можно использовать "denver"  или "open server". И вроде все остаются в в выигрыше. Если без php - Jquery `.load()`

Comment: ссылки запрещены этим проектом .. но на w3shools хорошо описан механизм : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Ссылки не запрещены на stackoverflow, не вводите людей в заблуждение. Откуда у вас вообще такая информация?

Answer (score 3):

**Вариант 1: Использование генератора статических сайтов.**

То есть есть программа в который вы визуально или посредством редактирования кода (или оба варианта) собираете сайт, например менюшка, футер, страницы и так далее. После этого программа генерирует статический код сайта на основе введённых данных. Дале можно обновить данные и пересобрать сайт.

Список генераторов статических сайтов тут - https://habrahabr.ru/company/selectel/blog/236441/

**Вариант 2: Использование JS.**

Делаете `js` файл, например с такой функцией.

```
var headerText = `<div>
Моя шапка
<span>Ещё код шапки</span>
</div>`;

function setHeader() {
  var header =  document.createElement("div");
  header.innerHTML = headerText ;
  document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', header );
}

setHeader();
```

Просто подключаете скриптовый файл в конце страницы, и header будет добавлен первым тегом в body.

Либо можно подключать в начале и вызывать функции на `onload` страницы.

Аналогично и с футером, только вставляем перед закрытием body, для этого вместо `afterbegin` пишем `beforeend`.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы используете при разработке Gulp, то есть довольно интересный плагин, который может вам помочь, а именно gulp-rigger. Суть этого плагина заключается в том что он может импортировать один файл в другой простой конструкцией.

Например, создаете отдельный файл header.html или footer.html. Далее просто подключаете его в основной index.html и во все последующие страницы вашего сайта вот так:

```
//= footer.html
```

При сборке gulp-проекта участок кода, записанный в вашем импортированном файлике будет на всех указанных местах.

Подробнее о плагине [тут](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rigger)

Answer (score 2):

Если не php, то тогда можно использовать javascript. Между шапкой и футером вставьте `<div id='content'></div>`. В зависимости от url меняйте его содержимое. Например `$("#content").append("<b>Appended text</b>");` Содержимым могут быть как данные, так и шаблоны ваших страниц.
Если использовать javascript, то лучше воспользоваться каким-нибудь js фреймворком.